# nltk edit distance lower than expected for tuple

Tags: nlp, nltk

While calculating the edit distance nltk does not seem to consider the changes correctly. For e.g.

```
edit_distance(('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), transpositions=True)
```

This returns 0 because the string match.

```
edit_distance(('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('selke', 'paravati', 'vital'), transpositions=True)
```

This returns 1 because transpositions is enabled. Else 2

```
edit_distance(('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('belke', 'paravati', 'vital'), transpositions=True)
```

This returns 2 because 1 point for transpositions and 1 for substitution.

```
edit_distance(('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('belke', 'zaravati', 'vital'), transpositions=True)
```

But when I change the spelling of the second word (from p to z) I still get the value of 2. The expected value is more than 2 because there are now 2 words changed.

---

In other words, the distance of these 2 words is 5 and the distance of the tuple that contains exactly same words is 3. This does not seem correct.

```
from nltk.metrics import edit_distance

edit_distance('vital', 'vataldedd', transpositions=True)

edit_distance(('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('selke', 'zaravatiasdf', 'vataldedd'), transpositions=True)
```

Expected distance for this tuple comparison is 5 or more.

---

Update:

I compared all the strings separately and took the total that returns 10 as expected.

```
s1, s2 = ('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('selke', 'zaravatiasdf', 'vataldedd')

final=list()
for i in s1:
    mylist=list()
    for k in s2:
        mylist.append(edit_distance(i, k, transpositions=True))
    final.append(min(mylist))

sum(final)
```

Is this approach correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th`edit_distance()` function expects strings as input. Simply, concatenate the substrings in each tuple into a single string.

```
>>> from nltk.metrics import edit_distance

>>> x, y = ('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('belke', 'zaravati', 'vital')
>>> x, y = " ".join(x), " ".join(y)

>>> x
'paravati selke vital'
>>> y
'belke zaravati vital'

>>> edit_distance(x, y)
13

>>> edit_distance(x, y, transpositions=True)
13
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `edit_distance` does not support tuple calculations, the expected input are a pair of strings. From the documentation:

```
:param s1, s2: The strings to be analysed
:param transpositions: Whether to allow transposition edits
:type s1: str
:type s2: str
```

The problem is that the function does not check that the values are of type `str`, so you can pass any object that supports indexing such as `tuple` or `list`. When you pass a pair of tuples to `edit_distance` the function considers each element of the tuple as a basic element. That is the reason the call:

```
d = edit_distance(('paravati', 'selke', 'vital'), ('belke', 'zaravati', 'vital'), transpositions=True)
```

returns 2, because there are two different elements `('paravati', 'zaravati'`) and `('selke', 'belke')`. To compute the total edit distance between a sets of strings you must wrap your code in a function, like this:

```
def total_edit_distance(s1, s2):
    final = list()
    for i in s1:
        mylist = list()
        for k in s2:
            mylist.append(edit_distance(i, k, transpositions=True))
        final.append(min(mylist))
    return sum(final)
```